# Can I change the default return type int in C?

Tags: c, return-type

Is there have any way that I can change the bit width of int in 64bit machine?

On a 64bit machine, int is 32bit and long is 64bit.

The next program will core, because the getenv function default returns int. But the char* is 64bit. I want to change the int bit width, or change the default return type to long:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf(getenv("HOME"));
}
```

Comment: May I ask why? You usually use it for error codes, and you cannot possibly need more than 4*10⁶.

Comment: "*the next program will core.because the getenv function default return int.but the char\* is 64bit.*" <- what? :o

Comment: Why dont you just include #include <stdlib.h> rather than looking for defaults, if your program segfaults its because you havent checked if getenv returns NULL

Comment: "`getenv` function default returns `int`". It is `char*` isn't ? [man getenv](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv)

Comment: The whole concept of default return type `int` is outdated and has been removed in C99.

Comment: Get the source code for your compiler and change it. You'll no longer have a C compiler and lots of things will break, but it shouldn't be too hard to do. Or, you know, just try to write correct code and enable compiler warnings, that's what the rest of us do to deal with this "problem".

Comment: Not really related to your question, but __never__ write `printf(x)` but rather `puts(x)` or `printf("%s", x)`. If `x` contains format specifiers you'll get undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

> because the getenv function default returns int

It does not. This is a C standard lib function defined as (C11 7.22.4.6):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
char *getenv(const char *name);
```

However, if you compile your code with an old, obsolete C compiler and fail to include `stdlib.h`, the return type will default to `int`. This was a design mistake of the C language which was fixed 18 years ago.

So the only reason why you would get `getenv` to return `int` would be if you have a bug in your program as you failed to include the relevant header `stdlib.h` *and* you are using an old, outdated compiler.

Fix this by adding `#include <stdlib.h>` and then also ensure that you are using a modern compiler<sup>1)</sup>.

---

<sup>1)</sup> gcc versions older than 5.x do for example default to the old, obsolete non-standard `-std=gnu90`. If you are using an old version of gcc, you must compile with one of the following options: `-std=c11` (preferred if supported) or `-std=c99`.